# How to use Moq to Mock an internal class protected method?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I have classes below:

```
public class TestService
{
     public void Upload()
     {
        var manager = new Manager();
        var worker = manager.CreateWorker();
        worker.DoWork();
     }
}

public class Manager
{
    public Worker CreateWork()
    {
        return new Worker();
    }
}

public class Worker()
{
     public void DoWork()
     {
        SetupEnvironment();
        //some codes here...
     }

     protected virtual void SetupEnvironment()
     {
       //some codes here ...
     }
}
```

I want to use Moq to create an unit test for Upload() method in TestService class, and SetupEnvironment() method of Worker should be mock up. I tried to the code below, but It doesnt' work:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Upload_Test()
{
        var mockWorker = new Mock<Worker>();
        mockWorker .Protected().Setup<string>("SetupEnvironment").Returns(() =>
        {
            //some dummy code here ...
        });

        var service = new TestService();
        service.Upload();
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
  }
```

Anybody knows how to make the above unit test code work?

Comment: Your mock object is OK, but your method under test use a real object instead of fake one. This is the problem....

Answer (score 1):

some things need to be changed. See the code of the class `TestService` and `Worker` below.

```
public class TestService
{
    private readonly Manager _manager;

    public TestService(Manager manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
    }

    public void Upload()
    {
        var worker = _manager.CreateWorker();
        worker.DoWork();
    }
}

public class Manager
{
    public virtual Worker CreateWorker()
    {
        return new Worker();
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        SetupEnvironment();
        //some codes here...
    }

    protected virtual void SetupEnvironment()
    {
        //some codes here ...
    }
}
```

Then the test could look like this. The method `SetupEnvironment` is `void` so the setup can't return any value and you need to mock the `Manager` as well and pass it to the `TestService` e.g. via *constructor injection* so you can inject your mock-object. HTH

```
[TestMethod]
public void Upload_Test()
{
    bool setupEnvironmentWasCalled = false;

    Mock<Worker> mockWorker = new Mock<Worker>();
    mockWorker.Protected().Setup("SetupEnvironment")
        .Callback(() =>
        {
            //some dummy code here ...
            setupEnvironmentWasCalled = true;
        });

    Mock<Manager> mockManager = new Mock<Manager>();
    mockManager.Setup(m => m.CreateWorker())
        .Returns(mockWorker.Object);

    var service = new TestService(mockManager.Object);
    service.Upload();
    Assert.IsTrue(setupEnvironmentWasCalled);
}
```